# googlemaps api v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I searched and tried but failed
I am using an older version of ez realty which seems to call google maps with this code:

```
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=<?php echo     $config->er_mapapi;?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which now produces a grey rectangle but no map anymore

Tried to replace that with v3 googlemap api :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo $config->er_mapapi;?>&sensor=false"></script>
```

but that just produces a white area where the map used to be, so obviously not calling the map right.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to provide a key if you are within free usage limits. 
Try to include it like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```